How to handle chrome extension updates without bothering the user?
I'm trying to work around a problem that has recently cropped up in my chrome extension. I was using the following code and it worked, until some point later and now it doesn't ...
My extension overrides new tab pages, and it also comes with a built-in page that's loaded
from the extension folder itself via "chrome-extension:" url.
Whenever an update is available I would send a message to my content script, and the script would re-load the current "extension" page via window.open and then reload itself, however in the new editions of Edge for example, the browser just quits as the reload causes the new about:blank page to be considered opened from the extension itself.
One way around it, would be sending the user to some internet web page, showing update is happening, which I'd like to avoid if possible ... and the issue is that if my extension's page is the only page open and a reload happens, the browser shuts down.
Wondering if anyone has any other solutions ...
From background:
chrome.runtime.onUpdateAvailable.addListener(function(details)
{
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow:true, active:true}, function(tabs)
    {
        // here I check to make sure my extension's page is open,- code hidden.
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {restart:"page"});
    });
});

And from content script:
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse)
{
    if (message.restart)
    {
        var clonePage = window.open("about:blank");
        clonePage.document.open();
        clonePage.document.write(document.documentElement.outerHTML);
        clonePage.document.close();
        chrome.runtime.reload();
    }
});

Edit:
I'm considering this to be a bug in Edge, as it still works correctly in the Opera browser and the new tab about:blank page opened by the extension is not closed when reload happens like it is in Edge ...
FIX I came up with just now, see below for explanation:
chrome.runtime.onUpdateAvailable.addListener(function(details)
{
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow:true, active:true}, function(tabs)
    {
        if (tabs.length > 0 && (tabs[0].url.includes(chrome.runtime.id+"/google.html") || tabs[0].url.includes(chrome.runtime.id+"/boogle.html")))
            chrome.tabs.create({url:"chrome://extensions/?id="+chrome.runtime.id});

        chrome.runtime.reload();
    });
});

chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow:true, active:true}, function(tabs)
{
    if (tabs.length > 0 && (tabs[0].url.includes("://extensions/?id="+chrome.runtime.id)))
    {
        chrome.tabs.create({url:homepage});
        chrome.tabs.remove(tabs[0].id);
    }
});

I check whether my extension's page is loaded, if not I just reload the extension, but if it is, I open my extensions details page, then reload, and then on restart check if the details page is open and replace with my extension's proper page ... it seems to work :)
===========================================================
After reading wOxxOm solution, here's my updated code:
// update available
chrome.runtime.onUpdateAvailable.addListener(function(details)
{
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow:true, active:true}, function(tabs)
    {
        if (tabs.length > 0 && (tabs[0].url.includes(chrome.runtime.id+"/google.html") || tabs[0].url.includes(chrome.runtime.id+"/boogle.html")))
            chrome.tabs.create({url:"data:text/plain,1800NOTHOME"});

        setTimeout(function() { chrome.runtime.reload(); }, 250);
    });
});

// update completed
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow:true, active:true}, function(tabs)
{
    if (tabs.length > 0 && (tabs[0].url.includes("1800NOTHOME")))
        chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, {url:homepage});
});

1800NOTHOME isn't unique enough, but just an example :)
